# Please explain how this line of code works?

Tags: java, linked-list

I am working with linked lists. I am trying to make a circular linked list, but I am having trouble understanding exactly what is going on. I have tried to map this out, but I just end up getting confused. But I think my biggest issues is here

prevLoc, list, newNode, and location are all linked list nodes.

here is the line i don't understand. the newNode link is set to list which is null.
what does list = newNode mean? does that just mean it is whatever element newNode is?

```
    if(prevLoc == null)
    {
        newNode.setLink(list);
        list = newNode;
    }
```

Here is the rest of the sorted class/add method for referenece.

```
public class CRefSortedList<T extends Comparable<T>>
    extends CRefUnsortedList<T>
    implements ListInterface<T>
{
    public CRefSortedList()
    {
        super();
    }

    public void add(T element)
    {
        LLNode<T> prevLoc;
        LLNode<T> location;
        T listElement;

        location = list;
        prevLoc = null;

        while(location != null)
        {
            listElement = location.getInfo();
            if(listElement.compareTo(element) < 0)
            {
                prevLoc = location;
                location = location.getLink();
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        LLNode<T> newNode = new LLNode<T>(element);

        if(prevLoc == null)
        {
            newNode.setLink(list);
            list = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            newNode.setLink(location);
            prevLoc.setLink(newNode);
        }
        numElements++;
    }
}
```

Comment: well i was unsure from the book. and my professor's "teaching" consists of having us type out code directly from the book, without really explaining or going over it what is happening. thus I have turned to stack overflow to get some guidance on what it means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(prevLoc == null) {
```

The case `prevLoc == null` can only occur if `element` is lower than the head of the list. In that case, the element must be added to the head of the list : that's what the two other lines mean.

```
    newNode.setLink(list);
    list = newNode;
}
```

First, we create a new node holding the value `element` and pointing to the head of the list. Then, we update `list` (which must be the head of the list) to point to the newly created node, since it is now the first node of the list.

Answer (score 0):

When inserting at the head of the list, the node you're inserting needs the existing list as its tail and you need to re-set the head to point to the new node. So I think that "list" = "head node" in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

The `list` variable is not defined in the code you presented, so we can't do more than guess about it.  If your class compiles, though, then `list` must be inherited from the superclass, `CRefUnsortedList`.  At a guess, it is a reference to the head node of the list, and the code you asked about is setting a new head node when you insert at the beginning of the list.

Comment: It seems pretty clear to me that `list` is the head of the list. Two hints : first, this is the node used to initialize the iteration over the list, and second it is the node used to point the new head of the list in the case `element <= list(0)`

Comment: @Dici, if the code presented is anywhere near *right*, then `list` must indeed be the superclass's reference to the head of the list, as you suppose and I guessed.  I have seen too much bad code, however, to take it for granted that the code presented is right.

Comment: yes, list was from the unsorted list. LLNode<T> list; list = null;